# Update android app version

Tags: android

Where do I have to change app version in code (androidManifest.xml I guess) to make an update?

I am having problems because I always get the same message from google.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to update following details,

```
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0"
```

Here each time you upload a new .apk you need to increase versionCode to +1. Changing of version code is **compulsory**.

So if you are uploading this app next time then you need to write following,

```
android:versionCode="2"
android:versionName="1.0"
```

Change in VersionName is optional if you do not want to change it. However if you want to change it then you can change it's value.

Comment: And I leave versionName as 1.0?

Comment: You'll probably want to change versionName too, but it's up to you.

Comment: if there is no major change in your update then you can ommit that part.

Comment: Also, in file.iml I see xml version=1.0... should I leave as 1.0?

Comment: You wont want to change the xml version number.

Comment: If you're too lazy to manage versionCode yourself, you can use this gradle plugin https://github.com/rockerhieu/Versionberg

Answer (score 6):

You can have a look at the docs at http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html

> **android:versionCode** — An integer value that represents the version of the application code, relative to other versions. The value is an
>   integer so that other applications can programmatically evaluate it,
>   for example to check an upgrade or downgrade relationship. You can set
>   the value to any integer you want, however you should make sure that
>   each successive release of your application uses a greater value. The
>   system does not enforce this behavior, but increasing the value with
>   successive releases is normative. Typically, you would release the
>   first version of your application with versionCode set to 1, then
>   monotonically increase the value with each release, regardless whether
>   the release constitutes a major or minor release. This means that the
>   android:versionCode value does not necessarily have a strong
>   resemblance to the application release version that is visible to the
>   user (see android:versionName, below). Applications and publishing
>   services should not display this version value to users.
>
> **android:versionName** — A string value that represents the release version of the application code, as it should be shown to users. The
>   value is a string so that you can describe the application version as
>   a .. string, or as any other type of absolute or
>   relative version identifier. As with android:versionCode, the system
>   does not use this value for any internal purpose, other than to enable
>   applications to display it to users. Publishing services may also
>   extract the android:versionName value for display to users.